# Angular Google Maps does not Display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

I have Angular Google Maps working it appears, but the map does not show on my website.  My JS loads the maps, I can print out the map properties.  Most importantly, when I go to my Chrome AngularJS Debugger, I can see a picture of the map living in my scope, but it doesn't show on my page.  On Google's API page, I can see requests are being made.  So what am I doing wrong to cause it to not actually display this map?  The view is being imported via the ng-view directive with ng-routes.

Thank you for any help!

[image: Image of developer pane]

Angular:

```
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: 'MY_KEY',
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    })

tripApp.controller('TripsController', ['$scope', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi',
    function ($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

        uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
            $scope.map = {center: {latitude: 39.8433, longitude: -105.1190}, zoom: 10};
        })
}])
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<script src="./assets/js/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/lodash.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/trips/viewtrips.css">

<div ng-controller="TripsController as tripCtrl">

    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.angular-google-map-container {
    height: 300px;
}
.angular-google-map {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Edit: Included my CSS import.  It appears that my CSS in my project is not loading properly.  Inspecting the element shows a zero height.  If I click on the element, it does not show my .css though it is imported.  I reproduced the code on fiddle and it works, but if I delete the css section, I get similar behavior.  If I run the code in liveEdit with PyCharm it gives me the issue, but if I modify the .css file while it's open in PyCharm, the map pops up!  Refresh - it's gone.

Before live-edit, the .angular-google-map css style in the developer pane of Chrome is not there where it lists all the styles for an element.  Then I modify the .css file with liveEdit and the map displays and the styles change to .angular-google-map from viewtrips.css line 7.  Why is it not loading the styles properly on first load?:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/diesel555/z12k2djv/2/

Comment: Hey Diesel. I have never used Angular Google Maps, but I have used [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) with Angular and never had a problem. It is extremely easy to use and get started. There are a lot more resources and information available with Google Maps API alone. If you already wrote a lot of code, then I hope someone helps you with your question!

Comment: NB: version 3.17 of the Google Maps API has been retired. It shouldn't be causing you any problem, you'll be getting v3.19 instead (the oldest available version).  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VersionDocs

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. I am using Angular Google Maps aswell. Try to set a background-color for .angular-google-map-container and your wrapper div. Does ist show anything?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  It looks like the API is working fine.  The element, if I had to guess is zero pixels.  Bastian - Setting a background color and container does not show anything for the angular-google-map-container, or the div. However if I change the background color of the div with Chrome during LiveEdit it applies and then the map pops up.  If I refresh, it all goes away.

Comment: Added an edit and fiddle code to update the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your map is not displaying - check if its height is zero in some debugger by inspecting the element.  If it is zero, your CSS is most likely not being imported properly.

My .css was being re-routed to a separate URL by the back end.  Solved by modifying back-end, but the generic answer is with no height set it defaults to zero so the most likely problem to look at is your .css file or the import.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check your css. Its actually pretty hard to get it fit the screen. This worked for me :

I had a nav bar that had 4em height and a sub nav bar with 64px height

```
.map-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100vh - 4em - 64px);
}

.angular-google-map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

with html

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
    <ui-gmap-google-map>
    ...
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem because og height is 0 or auto. Set height for agm-map will solve

```
agm-map{
    height: 500px
}
```